# How to get ssl certificate working with custom domain using aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, namecheap

I have my application hosted on `aws s3` bucket and domain on `Namecheap`.

on `Aws S3` i have 2 buckets named `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`

Have these settings on `Namecheap` like this

```
CName     www    http://www.mydomain.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

CName      @     www.mydomain.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
```

Now i have my website up n running on my www.mydomain.com but now i want to get ssl integrated with my domain. So how can i get the ssl certificate and use that in my domain to get `https` for my website using `aws` ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to setup a CloudFront Distribution that uses your S3 Bucket as source.

Generate an SSL Cert using Certificate Manager, this must be done in N-Virginia zone.

Use the cert in the CF Distribution, take the domain from there and update your `Namecheap` DNS records to point to the CF Dristribution.